# Android - Draw only parts which are visibile

Tags: android

I've created a custom view that draws via onDraw() overridden method some shapes. This view is scrollable so every time user navigates in the Activity, onDraw() method has called and all the canvas is drawn. In the onDraw() method there are some statements making some hard calculations so my intent is to draw, when user scrolls the view, only the part that were invisible and now, for the scrolling, they are visible.

How can I draw only the part that are visible in my custom view?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas sysCanvas)
{
    super.onDraw(sysCanvas);
    if(!giaDisegnato) //If I've never drawn before, let's draw
    {
        if(!listaTl.isEmpty())
        {
            toDisk= Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.RGB );
            canvas = new Canvas(toDisk);
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);      
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE); 
            p.setAntiAlias(true);   
            p.setStrokeWidth(1);
            for(TimelineGrafica t : listaTl)
            {
                if(inseritaLaPrima)
                     y = ySalvata + this.yAngoloDestroGiu + DISTANZA_FRA_TIMELINE;
                p.setColor(t.getColor());
                disegnaPunta(canvas,p,t);
                disegnaRettangolo(canvas,p,t);
                disegnaGrain(canvas,p,t);
                disegnaFatti(canvas,p,t);
                inseritaLaPrima = true;
            }
            y = ySalvata;
            inseritaLaPrima = false;
            sysCanvas.drawBitmap(toDisk,0,0,p);
        }
        requestLayout();
        giaDisegnato = true;
    }
    else
    {
        //Here I've already drawn. So I'd like to redrawn the part of the view that now 
       //is visible.    
        sysCanvas.drawBitmap(toDisk,0,0,p);         
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to the language, it is difficult to know precisely what you are doing.

However, you can check the canvas to know whether you should draw or not using [quickReject](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#quickReject(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Canvas.EdgeType)).

Example:

```
if(canvas.quickReject(boundingRect, EdgeType.BW)) {
    return;
}
```

Comment: You create a bounding rectangle for the element that you wish to draw. You give it the X, Y, X+Width, Y+Height of your element. Then it will do the rest.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't help. Maybe because I don't know how to use your statements in my code